# Fetch an email with imaplib but do not mark it as SEEN

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I want to parse some emails from a user 's inbox but when I do:

```
typ, msg_data = imap_conn.fetch(uid, '(RFC822)')
```

It marks the email as SEEN or read. This is not the desired functionality. Do you know how can I keep the email at its previous stare either SEEN or NOT SEEN?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You might also set `read_only` to true when selecting the folder:

```
imap_conn.select('Inbox', readonly=True)
```

Comment: This is unsuitable if you want to modify the folder for other reasons (say, remove some of the messages you have peeked at because they are spam, or whatever).

Comment: You may call `imap_conn.select('Inbox')` before modifying the folder and then `imap_conn.select('Inbox', readonly=True)` again. It's simpler and more reliable to use PEEK, of course.

Answer (score 24):

The following should work:

```
typ, msg_data = imap_conn.fetch(uid, '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])')
```

or `BODY.PEEK[TEXT]`, etc.

Comment: Simply `BODY.PEEK[]` gets the entire message without modifying `\Sent`.

Comment: BODY.PEEK[] does not work on gmail's IMAP implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `(RFC822.PEEK)` as the "message-parts" argument, according to [RFC 1730](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1730.html#section-6.4.5) (I have not verified which servers actually implement that correctly, but it doesn't seem hard for them to).

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work with Gmail but the previous answer did. Thank you anyway!

Comment: RFC1730 is long since obsoilete. The [RFC3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) equivalent is `BODY.PEEK[]`

Answer (score 0):

You may use imap_tools package: 
https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, Q

# get list of email subjects from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password') as mailbox:
    # mark_seen=False - not mark emails as seen on fetch
    subjects = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch(mark_seen=False)]
```