# How to get only subject,from and body of email using imaplib and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap

I want to fetch from,subject and body of an email using message_numbers of an email.
I don't want any attachments or images. Just plain text of body.
Can someone please help me with some code snippet? I am stuck at this point.

This is the current code snippet I am using to get the data:

```
import imaplib
import config
import bs4
import email

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(config.imap_server,config.imap_port)
r, d = imap.login(config.username, config.password)
imap.select("Inbox")
r, d = imap.uid('search', None, "ALL")
message_numbers = d[0].decode('utf8').split(' ')
for msg_uid in message_numbers:
    r, d = imap.uid('FETCH', msg_uid, '(RFC822)')
    try:
        raw_email = d[0][1].decode('utf8')
    except:
        raw_email = str(bs4.BeautifulSoup(d[0][1],'lxml'))
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    print(email_message) # here i need only subject,from and body in string format and i dont want attachments
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(all=True)):
        print(msg.subject)
        print(msg.from_)
        print(msg.text or msg.html)
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Regards, imap_tools author.

Answer (score 1):

Your code implements several incorrect assumptions.

You can't assume that an IMAP message is UTF-8 clean. In fact, chances are it isn't.

You can't assume an email body is HTML. Again, chances are, it isn't. Anyway, using BeautifulSoup and LXML to pick apart the *email message itself* is pretty crazy; use an `email` parser, not an XML parser. Python has one built in.

The Python `email` library has an older version which is still supported, but the new version in 3.6+ has a feature you definitely want here - it can try to guess what you mean by "the body" when there are multiple parts. Of course, this is a heuristic only; "the body" is not well-defined in a multipart message. Perhaps see also [What are the "parts" in a multipart email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562935/what-are-the-parts-in-a-multipart-email/48563281#48563281)

The IMAP `FETCH` command will mark messages as "seen"; perhaps you want to use `readonly=True` when selecting the inbox? See also [Fetch an email with imaplib but do not mark it as SEEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283460/fetch-an-email-with-imaplib-but-do-not-mark-it-as-seen)

```py
import imaplib
import config
# import bs4     # not used
import email
from email.policy import default  # for Python 3.6+ EmailMessage support

# Use a context manager
with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(config.imap_server,config.imap_port) as imap:
    r, d = imap.login(config.username, config.password)
    imap.select("Inbox", readonly=True)
    r, d = imap.uid('search', None, "ALL")
    message_numbers = d[0].decode('utf8').split(' ')
    for msg_uid in message_numbers:
        r, d = imap.uid('FETCH', msg_uid, '(RFC822)')
        message = email.message_from_bytes(d[0][1], policy=default)
        print("from:", message['from'])
        print("subject:", message['subject'])
        # Guess at "the" body part
        # Maybe parse this like before if it is an HTML part?
        print(message.get_body().get_content())
        print()
```